# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: test <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-grid

When we are trying to bind text (which may have both plain text and urls) in Kendo grid, we are getting "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: test http://google.com test " error

Please find the below method which I am binding for grid row.

```
function getLocationLink(data) {   
     if (data.ActionComment != '' && data.ActionComment != 'undefined') {
        var urlText = data.ActionComment; //urlText value is "test http://www.google.com test
        var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
        return urlText.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
        });
      }
    return data.ActionComment;
}
```

I could bind this anchor link in document.ready but the above function is executing after document.ready. So I dont have any option to bind this anchor link except here. 
Can someone please provide the solution for this.

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be within the function alone: http://jsfiddle.net/4dp84q87/.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, yes its working absolutely fine if we do normally in console.log. But the issue is occurring when we bind it to a div or kendo grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either wrapping the resulting string in another element, such as a `<span>`:

```
var result = urlText.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
});
return '<span>' + result + '</span>';
```

Or return DOM Nodes by [parsing the string directly](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) (note: jQuery 1.8 or later):

```
var result = urlText.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
});
return $.parseHTML(result);
```

---

The error you mentioned [is from Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/2.0.0/src/sizzle.js#L874-L876), the selector engine that's typically behind `jQuery(selector)`.

It suggests that the result from `getLocationLink()` is being passed to `jQuery()`, which is treating it [as a `selector`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) rather than [as `html`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

```
jQuery('test <a href>http://google.com</a> test');
// Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ...
```

Having the string start with `<`, as with the `<span>`, will convince `jQuery()` it's markup. And, providing [a collection of Nodes](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray) will avoid the conditional parsing.

```
jQuery('<span>test <a href>http://google.com</a> test</span>');
// [ <span>...</span> ]

jQuery(jQuery.parseHTML('test <a href>http://google.com</a> test'));
// [ "test ", <a>...</a>, " test" ]
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, you are absolutely right. Thanks a lot for the fix. But I am getting anchor link for the whole text "test http://google.com test".

Comment: If I see the source code for this element, <span> tag is rendering inside the <a> tag.  
Please find the below source code for this:
<a class="undefined" href="http://google.com"><span title="test http://google.com test http://gmail.com">test http://google.c...</span></a>